# Let $f : R → R^{2}$ be $ C^{∞} $. Does there exist $t_{o} ∈ (0, 1)$ such that $f(1) − f(0)$ is a scalar multiple of $df/dt| t=t_{o}$

Tags: calculus

Let $f : R → R^{2} $ be $C^{∞} $(i.e., has derivatives of all orders). Then there exists $t_{o} ∈ (0, 1)$
such that $f(1) − f(0)$ is a scalar multiple of $df/dt| t=t_{o}$ (true/false) $?$

This statement is equivalent to -

There exists a $t_{o}$ such that $f'(t_{o}) =( f(1)-f(0))/k$

This looks like mean value theorem but I don't know if it is applicable here.

How can I  proceed$?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The statement is true if $f'(t)$ is nowhere zero:*

If $f(0) = f(1)$ then $f(0) - f(1)$ is a scalar multiple of $f'(t_0)$ for any $t_0$.

Otherwise choose a non-zero vector $v$ which is orthogonal to $f(1) - f(0)$ and consider the real-valued function
$$
 g(t) = \langle f(t) - f(0), v \rangle \, .
$$
Then $g(0) = g(1) = 0$ and we can apply the mean-value theorem (or Rolle's theorem). It follows that for some $t_0 \in (0, 1)$
$$
 0 = g'(t_0) =  \langle f'(t_0), v \rangle \, .
$$
So $v$ is orthogonal to both $ f(1) - f(0)$ and $f'(t_0)$, and in two dimensions this implies that $ f(1) - f(0)$  is a scalar multiple of $f'(t_0)$.

*Without the restriction $f'(t) \ne 0$ the statement is wrong.*

To simplify the notation, I'll define a counterexample on the interval $[-1, 1]$ instead of $[0, 1]$.

$f(t) = (t^3, 1-t^2)$ satisfies $f(1) - f(-1) = (1, 0) - (-1, 0) =(2, 0)$, and that is not a scalar multiple of
$$
 f'(t) = (3t^2, -2t)
$$
for any $t \in [-1, 1]$.

Comment: Can I take the function $f(t) = (e^{t},t)$ for a contradiction$?$ since there is no such $t_{o}$ for which $(e-1,1)$ is scalar multiple of $ (e^{t},1)$.

Comment: @Mathsaddict: That is not a counterexample, $e^t = e-1$ has a solution in $(0, 1)$.

Answer (score 1):

It is false, if the scalar multiple is $ \ne 0.$ Take $f(t)=( \cos( 2 \pi t), \sin (2 \pi t)).$

Then $f(1)=f(0),$ hence $f(1)-f(0)=0,$ but $f'(t) \ne 0$ for all $t.$

Comment: But $k=0$ works in this case.